# Slack block markdown syntax not working in hashtable

Tags: powershell, slack, slack-block-kit

I'm generating a Slack message using a hashtable in Powershell.

Here is how the hashtable is generated:

```
$serviceitems = foreach ($r in $rows) {
    @{
        type = 'section'
        text = @{
            type = 'mrkdwn'
            text = "*{0}*\n{1:C2}" -f $r[1], $r[0]
        }
    }
    @{
        type = 'divider'
    } 
}
```

The messsages show up in Slack but the `\n` prints out instead of going to a new line like it should. The two `*` make the text bold as intended. I tried adding a backtick to before `\n` and also tried adding an extra `\`. Both made no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` has no special meaning in PowerShell strings.

PowerShell uses `` ` `` (the so-called backtick) as the escape character, so you need escape sequence `` `n `` inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in order to embed an actual newline (LF character) in the strings.

Simple example:

```
PS> "line 1`nline 2" | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
[line 1
line 2]
```

PowerShell happily accepts LF alone as a newline; if you do need CRLF newlines, use `` `r`n ``. To refer to the *platform-native* newline sequence, use `[Environment]::NewLine` (`$([Environment]::NewLine)` to use it inside `"..."`).

See also:

- The conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> I tried adding a backtick to before `\n` and also tried adding an extra `\`.

As implied at the top, `\` should not be in the picture at all.

Trying `` `\n `` results in `` ` `` escaping the `\` character, which has no effect (escaping a non-special character is ignored); in other words: `` "`\n" `` is the same as `"\n"` which is *verbatim* `\n`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if I needed to do Slack block syntax or Powershell syntax.